# Solving algebra equations

Tags: homework-and-exercises, cosmology

I am reading this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1004.4187) (this paper is now becoming an important paper on cosmological phase transitions). There are two known algebra equations (Eq. (2.9) in the paper)
$$(e_++p_+)\frac{v_+^2}{1-v_+^2}+p_+=(e_-+p_-)\frac{v_-^2}{1-v_-^2}+p_-, \tag{1}$$
$$(e_++p_+)\frac{v_+}{1-v_+^2}=(e_-+p_-)\frac{v_-}{1-v_-^2}. \tag{2} $$
Then it is mentioned that these two relations can be rearranged as
$$v_+v_-=\frac{p_+-p_-}{e_+-e_-}, \tag{3}$$
$$\frac{v_+}{v_-}=\frac{e_-+p_+}{e_+ + p_-}.\tag{4}$$

Although Eqs. (1), (2) are algebra equations, I found it very complicated to rederive Eqs. (3), (4) from (1), (2).

Since Eqs. (3), (4) look quite clean, I would guess there may be some clever way to derive them. Does anybody have any insights? And further, can Mathematica solve such algebra equations?

Comment: *can Mathematica solve such algebra equations?* Yes.

Comment: *Mathematica* (and presumably any other decent computer algebra system) can solve the simultaneous equations for $v_+$ and $v_{\_}$ with one command, Solve[]. You can then use the solution to compute their product and quotient. I got the expressions in (3) and (4).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from these two equations
$$(e_++p_+)\frac{v_+^2}{1-v_+^2}+p_+=(e_-+p_-)\frac{v_-^2}{1-v_-^2}+p_-, \tag{1}$$
$$(e_++p_+)\frac{v_+}{1-v_+^2}=(e_-+p_-)\frac{v_-}{1-v_-^2}. \tag{2} $$

Show that
$$v_+v_-=\frac{p_+-p_-}{e_+-e_-}, \tag{3}$$
$$\frac{v_+}{v_-}=\frac{e_-+p_+}{e_+ + p_-}.\tag{4}$$

---

Rewrite Eq.(1) as:
\begin{align}
& (e_++p_+)\frac{v_+^2}{1-v_+^2} +e_+ + p_+ - e_+=(e_-+p_-)\frac{v_-^2}{1-v_-^2} +e_- + p_- - e_-; \\
& (e_++p_+)\frac{1}{1-v_+^2} - e_+ =(e_-+p_-)\frac{1}{1-v_-^2} - e_-; \tag{5}\\
\end{align}

Add Eq.(2) to Eq.(5):
\begin{align}
& (e_++p_+)\frac{1+v_+}{1-v_+^2} - e_+=(e_-+p_-)\frac{1+v_-}{1-v_-^2} - e_-; \\
& (e_++p_+)\frac{1}{1-v_+} - e_+=(e_-+p_-)\frac{1}{1-v_-} - e_-; \\
& (e_++p_+) (1-v_-) - (e_+ -e_-) (1-v_+ - v_- + v_+ v_-) = (e_-+p_-)(1-v_+). \tag{6}
\end{align}

Then substract Eq.(2) from Eq.(5):
\begin{align}
& (e_++p_+)\frac{1-v_+}{1-v_+^2} - e_+=(e_-+p_-)\frac{1-v_-}{1-v_-^2} - e_-; \\
& (e_++p_+)\frac{1}{1+v_+} - e_+=(e_-+p_-)\frac{1}{1+v_-} - e_-; \\
& (e_++p_+) (1+v_-) - (e_+ -e_-) (1+v_+ + v_- + v_+ v_-) = (e_-+p_-)(1+v_+). \tag{7}
\end{align}

Then, add Eq.(6) and Eq.(7):
\begin{align}
& 2 (e_++p_+) - 2(e_+ -e_-) (1 + v_+ v_-) = 2(e_-+p_-).\\
& v_+ v_- = \frac{p_+ - p_- }{e_+ -e_-}. \tag{3}
\end{align}
This resembles Eq.(3).

Finally, Eq.(7) - Eq.(6):
\begin{align}
& 2 (e_++p_+) v_- - 2 (e_+ -e_-) (v_+ + v_-) = 2 (e_-+p_-) v_+;\\
& (e_+ + p_+) - (e_+ -e_-)\left( \frac{v_+}{v_-} + 1 \right)  = (e_- + p_-) \frac{v_+}{v_-};\\
& (e_+ + p_+) - (e_+ -e_-)  = (e_+ + p_-) \frac{v_+}{v_-};\\
& \frac{v_+}{v_-} = \frac{p_+ + e_- }{e_+ + p_-}. \tag{4} 
\end{align}